# MySQL: Using of INDEX but still very slow

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql **[InnoDB engine]** Index but the query response is still very slow (high response time):

I studied here [Full Text Search In MySql](http://www.designaeon.com/full-text-search-in-mysql/) that

> we can’t be implemented on Mysql default innoDB storage engine tables.

I created a auto-suggest where user type **City** name then my query fetches `City, Country` name format.

```
$search = $_GET['term'];
mysql_query("CREATE INDEX index_plc ON projects(pro_loc_city)");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT CONCAT_WS(', ', p.pro_loc_city, c.country_name) 
                       as location FROM projects p
                   LEFT JOIN countries c ON c.country_id = p.country_id 
                   WHERE p.pro_loc_city LIKE '%$search%' 
                   GROUP BY p.country_id") or die('Something went wrong');
mysql_query("DROP INDEX index_plc ON projects");
```

In firebug the response time is approx 5 to 3 seconds.

[image]

**Projects Table**

```
----------------------------------
pro_id | pro_loc_city | country_id
----------------------------------
   1     Karachi          50
   2     Lahore           60
   3     Karachi          50
   4     Abc              70
   5     Karachi          50
```

**Countries**

```
-------------------------
country_id | country_name
-------------------------
   50         Pakistan
   60         A Country
   70         B Country
```

This is what Firebug says.

[image]

please guide me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Creating an index on a large table is an expensive operation. Indexes are in most cases there to stay. Creating one, executing a query and dropping it - won't help the speed. Try creating the index, leaving it and query again :)

Comment: In firebug? what about the explain plan?

Comment: @favoretti: Your comment should be an answer.

Comment: @ypercube: thanks, added as an answer :) Not sure if it will help PHP Ferrari much though :)

Comment: @PHP: How many rows does the `projects` table have?

Comment: @favoretti: Yeah, the `LIKE '%search%'` will probably will not be helped by this index. But it at least will not be negatively affected by adding/removing an index every time it is run.

Comment: (i) you **must not** use get parameters within SQL querys without escaping them.  (ii) why not try a like `"$search%"` first and only fall back to a "%..." if this doesn't return any hits.  (iii) the index is only useful for likes without a leading wildcard, and in this case don't create and drop it, leave it place.

Comment: @TerryE & Vatev: Thanks a lot to guide me, I followed your suggestion & almost 50% solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating an index on a large table is an expensive operation. Indexes are in most cases there to stay. Creating one, executing a query and dropping it - won't help the speed. Try creating the index, leaving it and query again :)

Comment: Well I also create INDEX only once and remove DROP query for INDEX but it still very slow please recheck my question here I add Firebug response, some time it takes 22 sec. Kindly guide what should exact query be. Thanks

Comment: @PHPFerrari your problem is the `p.pro_loc_city LIKE '%$search%'`. MySQL can only use an index with `LIKE 'value'` or `LIKE 'value%'`. It can't use one for a full substring search. Your options are to either search for a city which begins with $search (`LIKE '$search%'`), or to create a [FULLTEXT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) index and do a 'full word' or a 'word begins with xxx' search.

Comment: @Vatev buddy city name is in Projects table & countries name are in countries table so what query would be to search string like "Karachi, Pakistan". AND one thing more i am using InnoDB

Please help me.